# Unknown encoding: idna - When using the "requests" library with Nuitka

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, nuitka

I am attempting to use the `requests` with Nuitka.

**example.py**

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://google.co.uk')
print r.text
```

I compiled a portable version of it using: `$ nuitka --portable example.py`.

I can browse to `example.dist` and execute `example.exe` perfectly on my machine.

However try run this on a different machine, I encountered a couple of errors:

> **ImportError: No module named _socket** - I fixed this by adding "_sockets.pyd" to the same directory.
>
> ---
>
> **LookupError: unknown encoding: idna** - I added `import encodings.idna` in attempt to fix it however it just results in **ImportError: No module named unicodedata**.

I am at loss at a loss as to what to do and cannot figure out how to fix this issue.

Can someone please help me?

***Note: You need to test the portable version on a machine (or virtual machine) that does not have Python, as it will appear to work on your machine.***

Comment: Is Nuitka the latest version?

Comment: @leovp The version is `0.5.25`.

Comment: For me, packaging `requests` didn't work with either 2.7, nor 3.6. Nuitka can't find files needed by `urllib3` which is inside `requests`. Did you try `--recurse-dir`?

Comment: @leovp I tried `nuitka --recurse-to=requests --portable example.py` and it still gave me `LookupError: unknown encoding: idna`.